# Building a python package to publish in pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi, pep517

I am greatly confused with the process of building a python package that I want to distribute on pypi.

There are some specific, basic things that I did not understand:

- What *exactly* is that gets published? Binaries? Source code? How do I do one or the other?
- How do I build multiple platform-specific, os-specific build from the same codebase?
- How do I build a the package for multiple versions of Python from the same codebase? Is it necessary if I want to support many python versions?

I am using a `.toml` file for the setup configuration.
I found some answers only, but all refer to procedures with either a `setup.py` or a `setup.cfg`.

Comment: The details really matter -- please share a link to the github repo where you are developing the source code + .toml config. We don't even know the set of languages involved, e.g. python + f77.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is that gets published? Binaries? Source code?

Yes, and yes.
It depends on details of your project and your package config.
Arbitrary commands can be run during a package build.
You might, for example, run a fortran compiler locally
and ship binaries, or you might insist that each person
installing the package run their own local fortran compiler.

We usually expect full `*.py` source code will appear on pypi.org.
"Binaries" here will usually describe compiled machine code,
and not `*.pyc` bytecode files.

> How do I build multiple platform-specific, os-specific build from the same codebase?

I have only done this via `git pull` on a target platform, followed
by a local build, but there is certainly support for cross target
toolchains if you need that.

> How do I build a the package for multiple versions of Python from the same codebase?

Same as above -- do a build under each separate target version.

> Is it necessary if I want to support many python versions?

Typically the answer is "no".
Pick a minimum required interpreter version, such as `3.7`,
and do all your development / testing / release work in that.

Backward compatibility of interpreters is excellent.
Folks running `3.8` or `3.11` should have no trouble
with your package.

There *can* be a fly in the ointment.
Suppose your project depends on library X,
or depends on X which depends on Y.
And one of them stopped being updated a few years ago,
or went through a big change like a rename.
Your users who are on `3.11` might find it
inconvenient to obtain a compatible version of X or Y.
This *might* motivate you to do split releases,
for example via major version number or by
slightly altering your project name.
Clearly you haven't crossed that bridge quite yet.

---

The [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs) ecosystem
is reasonably mature. It has tried to fix many of the
rough edges surrounding the python packaging practices
of the last few decades. I recommend that you prefer
modern over ancient practices, and that you adopt poetry
for your project.

If that won't fly for some reason, and especially if
binaries are a big deal for your project, consider publishing via
[conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge).
There are many `pip` pitfalls with target system
needing compilers and libraries. Conda does an
excellent job of ensuring that `conda install ...`
will Just Work.